# determine if $\int _0^\infty x^{-3/4}e^{-x}dx$ converges

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

> I want to determine if this integral convergent or not
> $$
> \int _0^\infty x^{-3/4}e^{-x}dx
> $$

I break up this integral into two pieces
$$
\int_0^1 x^{-3/4}e^{-x}dx  + \int_1^\infty x^{-3/4}e^{-x}dx 
$$

I compared the second part with $e^{-x}$ and concluded that it is convergent. However, how can I show that $\int_0^1 x^{-3/4}e^{-x}dx$ is also convergent?

Comment: Compare to $\int_0^1 x^{-3/4} \, dx$. The point with these kinds of comparisons is always "what's a function that's just a little bit bigger than this one in relative terms?" when showing convergence (or smaller when showing divergence).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer